# Is there a version of Tensorflow 1.1x that is compatible with CUDA 10.2

Tags: tensorflow

Does any know if there is a version of Tensorflow 1.1x that is compatible with CUDA 10.2?

Answer (score 0):

The following images provide an overview of the officially tested combinations of CUDA and TensorFlow on Linux, macOS and Windows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Windows:**

[image: Windows:]

[image]

For the updated information please refer [Linux & macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) and [Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations).